# Save the current continuation in SMLofNJ

Tags: smlnj, callcc

I was reading through [this](http://matt.might.net/articles/programming-with-continuations--exceptions-backtracking-search-threads-generators-coroutines/) funny page explaing continuations in racket.

They present code to save the current continuation of a computation (and use this trick later to implement backtracking). The code looks as follows:

```
(define (currcc)
 (call/cc (lambda (cc) (cc cc))))
```

Now I'd like to do the same trick in Standard ML, and since SML of New Jersey seems to be the only interpreter implementing continuations I'm doing it there.

The [continuation signature](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/SMLofNJ/pages/cont.html) there looks as follows:

```
type 'a cont
val callcc : ('a cont -> 'a) -> 'a
val throw : 'a cont -> 'a -> 'b
val isolate : ('a -> unit) -> 'a cont
```

The direct translation would be:

```
val currcc () = callcc (fn cc => throw cc cc)
```

but the type system of ML forbids this (as this is circular).

So I tried something like:

```
val glcc = ref (isolate (fn x => ()) : unit cont)    
fun savecc () = (callcc (fn (cc : unit cont) => glcc := cc); !glcc)
fun backjump () = throw (!glcc) ();
```

and various other tricks with references, but I can't find a way to really save the current continuation (because I change the wanted continuation by the use of !glcc afterwards, in this example).

Does anybody know about a way to implement operators `savecc` and `backjump` that let me save the current continuation of a program and jump back to that point afterwards in Standard ML?

Many thanks in advance!

Yannick

Comment: This seems relevant: http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.functional/continuations-in-sml/1053433